# Text to speech in HTML5, JavaScript which runs on all browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text-to-speech

I have created one sample example for text to speech in HTML5 using JavaScript which runs on only Chrome, but when I am trying to run it on other browser i.e. IE, Mozilla, Safari nothing will happen. What should I do to run my text to speech demo code on all browsers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#startBtn").on('click', function (e) {
                debugger;
                var u1 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello Word..');
                u1.lang = 'en-US';
                u1.pitch = 1;
                u1.rate = 1;
                //u1.voice = voices[10];
                u1.voiceURI = 'native';
                u1.volume = 1;
                speechSynthesis.speak(u1);

            });
        });
    </script>
    <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="startBtn" value="Hello Word.." />
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It does not support Mozilla and it does not support IE. It does support Safari, and worked fine for me.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy :- Thank you Sir for your reply, I will again check it on safari.

Comment: working nice. can we give the time delay between two strings? is this possible?

Comment: You can explore support for SpeechSynthesisUtterance in the chart at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance and https://caniuse.com/?search=SpeechSynthesisUtterance -- if it's not working on a particular browser it's important to debut all the parts of the page. Here 9 years after your question, support is a good deal better!

Answer (score -1):

See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vijaypancholi2626/gmxz7b65/)

```
// Check if the browser supports the SpeechSynthesis API
if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {

// Get the text to be spoken from the input field

var textToSpeak = document.getElementById('startBtn').value;

    // Create a new SpeechSynthesisUtterance instance

    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(textToSpeak);
    
    // Use the default voice
    var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    
    utterance.voice = voices[0];

    // Speak the text
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
} else {
    alert('Text-to-speech is not supported in this browser.');
}
```

Comment: Use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) instead of bare code and a link to some other site. Also, this looks a lot like what the OP already has; it just checks for support first.