# Text to Speech Conversion for web application

Tags: javascript, java, html, text-to-speech

Hello guys i want to convert a text entered in a textfield in to voice in a browser. I have tried two way that i have mentioned below but it has some problems. I need a better solution for Text to Speech and also may any one have any idea to implement it in better way.

**Method 1---**

I have tried freeTTS which is available free in java and convert text into a **.wave** audio file.

Using following code I have created a web service, whenever user hits a web service with a text which is to converted into **.wave** audio file then play that audio file at client browser using HTML5 `<audio>` tag.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
      FreeTTS freetts;
      AudioPlayer audioPlayer = null;
      System.setProperty("freetts.voices", "com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory");
      String voiceName = "kevin16";

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Using voice: " + voiceName);

      //The VoiceManager manages all the voices for FreeTTS.

      VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
      Voice helloVoice = voiceManager.getVoice(voiceName);

      if (helloVoice == null) 
      {
        System.err.println(
            "Cannot find a voice named "
            + voiceName + ".  Please specify a different voice.");
        System.exit(1);
      }

      helloVoice.allocate();//Allocates the resources for the voice.
      audioPlayer = new SingleFileAudioPlayer("/home/rohit/voicefiles/file4",Type.WAVE);  //create a audioplayer to dump the output file   
      helloVoice.setAudioPlayer(audioPlayer);//attach the audioplayer 
      helloVoice.speak("Hi this it rohit");//includes text to be converted in mp3
      helloVoice.deallocate();//Clean up and leave.
      audioPlayer.close();//don't forget to close the audioplayer otherwise file will not be saved

      System.exit(0);
}
```

Problem with above code is

1. If there are lots of hits to the web service obviously it creates
   lots of .wave audio files which may lead to storage problem at some
   time. I have solved this problem by executing batch that identifies the no. of audio file have excluded a specific no. then i am deleting old files, but this solution is not very much good
2. Also this process is time consuming, after hitting a web service with long text it requires some time for voice to play at client browser.
3. In freeTTS i did not found any female voices, i have used male voice as kevin16 which does not sound user friendly, it sounds like machine.

**Method 2---**

Another method for Text to Speech is use of external api's. I have used google api which work with front end only which reduces the server load.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function textToVoice()
  {
      var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
      var text = document.getElementById("textToRead").value;
      var lan = 'en-EN'

      msg.voice = voices[10]; // Note: some voices don't support altering params
      msg.voiceURI = 'native';
      msg.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
      msg.rate = 1; // 0.1 to 10
      msg.pitch = 1; //0 to 2
      msg.text = text;
      //msg.lang = 'hi-IN';
      msg.lang = lan;
      msg.onend = function(e) {
        console.log('Finished in ' + event.elapsedTime + ' seconds.');
        location.reload();
      };

      speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <textarea id="textToRead" rows="25" cols="100"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Listen" onclick="textToVoice()" />
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

It generates good voice with different country specific accent, still there are problems like

1. It's not free
2. It requires active internet connection
3. It is browser specific, it does not work in internet explorer

Comment: For ease of use I'd recommend https://responsivevoice.org/ - however it is again not free (surprising how many companies want to make money, right?).

Comment: i have already checked responsivevoice.org it's not free that's other thing but it requires internet connection which is not allowed in my project

Comment: Whilst it doesn't work in IE, the W3C Web Speech API is free and works offline. https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/webspeechapi.html#tts-section

Comment: Also asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671115/text-to-speech-in-html5-javascript-which-runs-on-all-browser

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please go through this [URL](https://blog.powerupcloud.com/text-to-speech-using-javascript-and-python-e025817251f0). i have a solution for this.

Comment: It's a same thing that Stuart Ervine suggested in comment reponsivevoice.js

Comment: Oh. i didnt see the comment section. But now i understood.but without internet conection it is not possible to convert text into voice. Please go through the polly service in the same blog.